# How to use the -pgo-instr-gen arguments with llvm opt

Tags: llvm, pgo

I want to test the `PGO` with `llvm` and I find most of the tutorial in the internet uses `clang` with argument `-fprofile-instr-use` to enable `PGO` instrumentation. However, what I have is an `llvm` bitcode file instead of the source code and I want to apply `PGO` to these bitcode files. I noticed the `opt` tool has the argument `-pgo-instr-gen`.

However, after I applied it to my bitcode like:

```
opt -pgo-instr-gen input.ll -o output.ll
```

and then tried to run the `output.ll` with `lli`, I got a segmentation fault. So, what is the correct way to enable `PGO` in such cases?